# Using immediate=true in Salesforce OAuth flow

Tags: oauth2, immediate

## Background

I am attempting to use the immediate parameter to check if a Salesforce user has already approved access when going through the Web Server OAuth Flow as documented on [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en). My reasoning for this is that I do not want the login or consent prompts to appear so I can reject access if they have not already approved.

Once the callback page is hit, I am always receiving the parameter `error=immediate_unsuccessful` even if the user has approved the application before and is logged in.

I have attempted to check this via a customised [Google OAuth 2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step1&scopes=api%2Crefresh_token&url=https%3A//&content_type=application/json&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=checked&oauthEndpointSelect=Custom&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https%3A//login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize%3Fimmediate%3Dtrue&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https%3A//login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token&includeCredentials=unchecked&accessTokenType=bearer&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&prompt=consent&response_type=code) and setting immediate=true or immediate=false to the end of the authorize endpoint. On =false, the consent prompt shows and then you can grant access. On =true, this returns the same error as listed previously.

The Connected App that has been set up has api and refresh_token as the available scopes, users are able to authorize themselves and there are no ip restrictions set. The client id and secret from this app is then passed into the OAuth 2 Playground.

Below is a brief example on how my proper application redirects to the auth url using Java and the Google OAuth client library. We initially authorize the client without the immediate and then later on call the same code with immediate=true (shown in example)

```
AuthorizationCodeFlow authorizationCodeFlow = new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod(), 
            httpTransport, 
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), 
            new GenericUrl("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"),
            new ClientParametersAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET), 
            CLIENT_ID,
            "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize")
            .setCredentialDataStore(StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(MemoryDataStoreFactory.getDefaultInstance()))
            .build();

    AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authUrl = authorizationCodeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl()
        .setRedirectUri("https://72hrn138.ngrok.io/oauth/callback")
        .setScopes(ImmutableSet.<String> of("api", "refresh_token"))
        .set("prompt", "consent")
        .set("immediate", "true");

    response.redirect(authUrl);
```

## Question(s)

- Are there any settings that I may have missed in Salesforce that would alleviate the error?
- Does the immediate setting even work?

Comment: Is this on a `Visualforce Page`? Can you please **[edit]** your post to include any relevant code? Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson This is for the OAuth flow and is not related to the immediate attribute on Visualforce (commandLink and commandButton). I have included a Java example when redirecting the user to the authorize endpoint. The issue can be replicated on the OAuth Playground link.

Comment: This question seems like it belongs on [so]. It is only peripherally related to Salesforce.